# Alt+Tab - want it limited to current monitor in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, window-manager, application-switcher

I generally use a quick flick of the mouse to switch focus between windows on different monitors. I generally keep the same application on a particular monitor so know where it 'lives'. I usually use the Keyboard <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle between windows that are covered by others, so from that POV it's quite confusing when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> causes windows on the *other* monitor to the one I'm looking at get cycled.

Is there any way to limit the list of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> windows only to the current monitor that has focus?

I'm on GNOME, not Compiz, on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Scripting - would be a piece of cake. You would miss the animation though, is that an issue? Would require an additional shortcut (or replacing the current).

Comment: Wait, forgot I already wrote it...

Comment: Hi EoghanM, just curious, but did you notice the answer? Do you manage?

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

[This snippet](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/experimental/tree/master/unreleased_ready_to_use/nopreviews) was written on request for Ubuntu Budgie, but should work on anything *but* Wayland. It switches between windows *on current workspace & monitor*, and, depending on the possible argument, either *between all windows* or *between windows of the active application*.
It doesn't show any animations though, it just cycles through windows.

Setup instructions are in the link.

*Disclaimer*: I am the author

Comment: This is great, thanks and works as described!
I'm gonna try it out for a while before accepting; it feels weird currently as I'm definitely accustomed to the window preview functionality.
BTW to set an ALT-TAB shortcut in Gnome Settings you first have to remove ALT-TAB from the current shortcut (otherwise it just executes an alt-tab!)

Comment: I'm getting the following warning on the console FYI
```./nopreviews.py:36: DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Window.get_pointer is deprecated
  return Gdk.get_default_root_window().get_pointer()[1:3]
```

Comment: Hmmm, actually I'm realising that this behaviour is very different from the previous as it cycles through all windows.  The basic 'quick' usage of Alt-Tab is used to toggle between 2 windows i.e. between current window and last opened window.
The default version with previews only enters the 'cycle' mode when you keep ALT held down (and further allows you to go backwards if you hold down SHIFT).

Comment: Ah, right I can easily make it switch according window stack (previous active first) would that help?

Comment: I actually think the whole `ALT-TAB` paradigm is broken. It was a blind inheritance from MSWindows and I've got a feeling it violates some core principals of UI design!
I've tried something else; I've bound your script to `ALT+2` and made another version of your script which goes in the reverse direction (`wins[1] - 1` instead of `wins[1] + 1`) which I've bound to `ALT+1`. So now I have more direct control of the cycling back or forward.  Gonna try this out for a while.

Comment: Probably the best thing would be to also detect for a SHIFT key being pressed to cycle in the reverse direction, however I don't know if that's possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the [Current screen only on window switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437/current-screen-only-for-alternate-tab/) extension or the [Alt-Tab for Dual Monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3148/alt-tab-for-dual-monitor/) extension. They both work similarly and cycle windows on the current monitor (the one with the mouse) only.

Although it is mentioned in the GNOME Shell extensions webpage that they support GNOME Shell versions up to 3.32, they both work fine for versions at least up to 3.36 (that's what I've tested).

Also see this question for how to install GNOME Shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)